Conditional Nodes in Kedro Pipelines
In Kedro, I have a pipeline with various nodes. However, based on the output of a certain node, I'd like to skip the next node. It is possible to determine a specific pipeline at the initialisation of the run, but not change the nodes to use during the run.
A solution I thought of is to create a node class, which takes a specific "skip_node" argument as input, which can be set based on the output of a previous node (or perhaps through a hook). However, this is a bit of a hacky solution. Is it possible to make nodes conditionally skippable during runtime?

There's currently no built in way to do that in Kedro. We've got several open issues requesting something similar (https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro/issues/2410). Feel free to comment on those, it helps with prioritisation.
